# C file synchronization

Tags: c, file, synchronization

I would like to open a file in C where the reads and writes are both synchronized. Is the proper way

```
    fopen("file.txt", O_DSYNCH | O_RSYNCH)
```

or

```
    fopen("file.txt", O_SYNCH)
```

This is for use on Linux

Comment: Neither: `fopen` doesn't take an `oflag`. Did you mean `open`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man 3 open`:

> If both `O_DSYNC` and `O_RSYNC` are set in `oflag`, all I/O operations on the file descriptor shall complete as defined by synchronized I/O data integrity completion.

Therefore, the correct call is

```
open("file.txt", O_DSYNC | O_RSYNC);
```

Note that `fopen` does not take `O_` flags (it uses mode strings like `"r+"`), and you therefore cannot use any of the `O_*SYNC` options with it directly.

Comment: And just to make this clear, use `open` followed by a call to `fdopen`, passing the descriptor you got back from `open`, to get your `FILE` pointer.

Comment: To achieve the same results with stdio streams, you need to (1) call `setvbuf` to turn off buffering on the stream, and (2) use `fcntl(fileno(f), F_SETFL, fcntl(fileno(f), F_GETFL) | O_DSYNC | O_RSYNC);`

Comment: @moretension: your solution works too, but don't forget to turn off buffering if you want guarantees that the data is written immediately.

Comment: Hi, Does it mean that with fopen we can do read/write synchronization call ? (only to buffer first)